# How to iterate through a hashmap with value as an arraylist for a given index

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have an hashmap savedQuestionAnswer with Integer as key and ArrayList as value in the following code

```
<c:set var="form" value="${surveyQuestionnaire}"/>
    <c:forEach var="questionName" items="${form.questionsList }"  varStatus="theCount">
 Q.<c:out value="${questionName}"></c:out>
<c:forEach items="${savedQuestionAnswer[(theCount.count).longValue()]}" var="choice" varStatus="choiceStatus">
       <br/> ${choiceStatus.count})${choice} 
     </c:forEach> <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

I am trying to print a questionnaire with multiple answers . So for each question (present in questionName) I have saved the list of answer in the hash map `savedQuestionAnswer` with corresponding  index value .

I am getting a syntax error,

> "The function longValue must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified".

Not able to get what is the correct syntax or way to accomplish it

Answer (score 0):

[LoopTagStatus.getCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) returns int. Why do you need:

```
${savedQuestionAnswer[(theCount.count).longValue()]}
```

Try simply

```
${savedQuestionAnswer[theCount.count]}
```

Also note that

- LoopTagStatus.getCount() starts counting at 1
- LoopTagStatus.getIndex() starts counting at 0

so depending on how you populate your HashMap, you should use

> theCount.index

or

> theCount.count

as a key.